In Webflux TraceID not Populated in Thread Created by Executer Service Pool
I'm encountering an issue with a Webflux application where the TraceID is not being populated in a thread created from the ThreadPool. Here's the scenario:
I have a Webflux application where I'm using reactive programming. When a request comes in, it goes through various processing steps, including calling external services. To track the request throughout these steps, I'm using Spring Cloud Sleuth for distributed tracing, which is integrated with my application.
However, I've noticed that when a request is handled by a thread from the ThreadPool (created by ExecuterService), the TraceID is not propagated to subsequent threads. This leads to difficulties in tracing the request across different components.
public Function<Order, Mono<Order>> getOrder() {
        return order -> {
            OrderListener listener = new OrderListener(order);
            Future<Order> event = executorService.submit(listener);
            try {
                order = event.get(maxWaitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } 
            return Mono.just(order);
        };
    }

Listener code where no trace id getting polpulated:
class OrderListener implements Callable<Order> {
    Override
    public Order call() throws Exception {
        ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration = document.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirestoreException error) {
                LOGGER.info("id: {}, orderStatus: {}", order.getId(), updatedStatus); // here no traceID in this log
                
                // rest codes
            }
        });
        return order;
    }
    }```



I tried to use contextCapure() on mono but that also didn't work.

